# A problem on geometric random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X_i, i \geq 1,$ be independent uniform (0, 1) random variables, and define $N$ by $$N=\min\{n:X_n < X_{n-1}\}$$. I need to prove that $$P\{N \geq k \mid X_0=x\} = \frac{(1-x)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$$. I understand that $N$ is a geometric random variable. I am stuck when finding the quantities like $P(X_i \geq X_{i-1} \mid X_{j} \geq X_{j-1}, \forall j\lt i)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathrm{P}\{N\ge k\mid X_0=x\}$ is the probability that at least the first $k$ entries are in non-decreasing order when the first entry is $x$. I think there is a simpler approach.

Since the entries are uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, the probability of two entries being equal is $0$. So we will assume that none are equal.

Given that $x_0=x$, the probability that the next $k-1$ entries are at least $x$ is $(1-x)^{k-1}$. In only one of the $(k-1)!$ permutations of those $k-1$ elements are they in non-decreasing order. Thus,
$$
\mathrm{P}\{N\ge k\mid X_0=x\}=\frac{(1-x)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to the question (although I think that robjohn's answer is the best). Conditionning with respect to $X_1$, we have that
$$
\begin{align}
P(N \geq k \mid X_0 = x) &= \int_0^1 P(N \geq k \mid X_0=x,X_1=y)\,dy \\
& = \int_x^1P(N \geq k \mid X_1 = y)\,dy\\
& = \int_x^1P(N \geq k-1\mid X_0=y)\,dy
\end{align}
$$
for all integer $k \geq 1$. The result then follows by induction.